# I have an eTA but my passport is in another embassy. Can I still travel to Canada with a copy of my passport?

Tags: air-travel, canada, iranian-citizens, air-canada, us-permanent-residents

I applied for an eTA to travel to Canada, and I already have it, but then I've sent my passport to the UK embassy for a tourist visa and I didn't get my passport back yet. I have a flight to Canada in 4 days. If I do not get my passport until then, can I still travel to Canada with a green card, valid ID, eTA and a copy of my passport?

Comment: btw im Iranian citizen

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you [need your passport](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=593&top=16):

> As a U.S. Green Card holder, you do not need a visitor visa to travel to Canada. However, you are expected to have an eTA if you plan to fly to or transit through Canada.
>
> When flying to Canada, you will need to present:
>
> - proof of status in the U.S. (such as a valid Green Card), and
> - your valid passport that you used to apply for your eTA.
>
> The border services officer will verify your eTA when you arrive in Canada.
>
> When travelling by land or sea directly from the U.S., you will only need to provide proof of your U.S. lawful permanent resident status (such as your Green Card).

The last paragraph means that it's possible to enter Canada without your passport, but only if you travel by land or sea.  Therefore, if you need to go to Canada without your passport, you could fly to a nearby city and cross by land.  Otherwise, you'll need to wait until you have your passport.

Comment: Wait, what if OP doesn't hold an ETA-eligible passport?

Comment: @JonathanReez it doesn't matter what passport you hold if you have a green card.